# Rails 3 create form for Polymorphic Association's child model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My application's route.rb file contains this namespace:

```
 namespace :admin do
       resources :index
       resources :posts do
           resources :images
         end
       resources :statics
     end
```

I used Polymorphic Association
Post model:   `has_many :images, :as => :imageable`
Image model: `belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true`
And I created necessary fields in migration.

When I call @post.images, no error message, I think this relation works fine.
I think, my problem is in the image uploader form, I use code like this: (post/edit action)

```
[there is post edit form]
<% form_tag admin_post_images_url( @post ) , :multipart => true do %>
    <%= file_field  :imageable, :photo, :size => 40 %>
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="upload!" />
<% end %>
```

The image is successful uploaded, but imageadble_id and _type doesnt filled. Something wrong (I think with admin_post_images_url( @post ) part), what is the problem?

**update:**
When I add manual to create imageadble_id and type, and listing its work, so assotiation is works good.

Comment: what are the params that get passed when you upload the image?

Comment: [1m[35mAREL (0.2ms)[0m  INSERT INTO `images` (`created_at`, `photo_file_name`, `imageable_type`, `imageable_id`, `photo_content_type`, `updated_at`, `photo_file_size`, `title`) VALUES ('2011-07-09 18:20:36', 'Screen shot 2011-06-25 at 5.10.25 PM (2).png', NULL, NULL, 'image/png', '2011-07-09 18:20:36', 266818, NULL)

Comment: i mean the parameters passed when you submit the form: "Parameters: {:imageabletype => } etc etc

Comment: Parameters: {"commit"=>"upload", "imageable"=>{"photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x1039988c0 @original_filename="kep-of-the-nap.png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"imageable[photo]\"; filename=\"kep-of-the-nap.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/CT/CTH+45itELiTh61FsqfSMU+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110710-4972-1xjam5q-0>, @content_type="image/png">}, "authenticity_token"=>"JLmrKyDgP4WaZdfLpZIf6SpGCNUCEX52E7KVNEhtgVs=", "utf8"=>"✓", "post_id"=>"1"}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<% form_for([:admin, @post, @image], :multipart => true) do %>
```

This may not work exactly but should get you started down the right path. No matter what, you need "form_for" if you're working with a model, not "form_tag".